# Facebook SDK OOP Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I converted a simple login / register script (with facebook connect) to oop.
But now when I call getUser() i get an error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object
```

Anyone know how I can fix it? Thanks.
ps. the facebook sdk is included.

```
    private $facebook;
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host, $app_id, $secret)
    {
        if (empty($_SESSION)) {
            $this->facebook    = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $app_id,
                'secret' => $secret,
                'cookie' => true
            ));
            $this->db = new ezSQL_mysql($db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host);
        } else {
            $this->Redirect('index.php');
        }
    }


    public function Login()
    {
        $session = $this->facebook->getUser();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Facebook class/function, and there doesn't seem to be anything attached to your post. It would be helpful if I could actually look at the Facebook class/function you call here:

```
$this->facebook    = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $app_id,
                'secret' => $secret,
                'cookie' => true
            ));
```

For whatever reason, this function is failing so $this->facebook is not an object (much like you'd get the same error on $db->blah if your db connection failed.

You might want to trap the Facebook class/function to see what's actually going in.